# Error decoding JSON data: quoted object property name expected

Tags: update

We're having issues with our website. We have migrated our Joomla content through J2XML to our new server where we started almost fresh (except the imported content, which was later imported to K2 component). We started on Joomla 3.5.1. Today we have noticed an issue with opening these imported articles, when trying to open them, we get an error:

> Error decoding JSON data: quoted object property name expected

Some of these older articles can be opened though, but they were modified prior to the update to Joomla 3.6.5.

Any ideas what to do? Well, except pulling the website from the backup that was taken before the update ... unfortunately there was some work done and no backup taken in this one day after the backup.

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: Well, pulling the website from the backup that was taken before the update might be helpful, as you could check if that issue pre-existed of the update. With that clue in your hands, you could get a better direction for the cause of your issue.

Comment: I put the backup to the testing server and the problem doesn't exist there. So it must have been the update.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
I checked the file /administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/view.html.php. One of the solutions was to change this part:

```
FilterOutput::objectHTMLSafe($item, ENT_QUOTES, array(
            'video',
            'params',
            'plugins'
        ));
```

However, the code was not exactly the same, it starts with:

```
JFilterOutput...
```

So the solution was to change it to:

```
JFilterOutput::objectHTMLSafe($item, ENT_QUOTES, array(
            'video',
            'params',
            'plugins',
                        'metadata'
        ));
```

Jan